# Integrate Layer.com's chatting api in Android

Tags: java, android

I have been trying to integrate [Layer.com's](https://developer.layer.com/docs/android) chatting api in my android application.

The demo project given by [Layer.com](https://developer.layer.com/docs/android) works fine, but when I implement it with my requirement the app crashes more than thee times and works fine there after.

Here is how my app should look like

Screen 1: (Select a user to make conversation from the side menu)

[image]

Screen 2: (When user1 is selected the conversation should look like this)

[image]

But As far as i have tried with the sample code from https://github.com/layerhq/quick-start-android here is what my output is
Screen 3:

[image]

The design for the [Layer.com](https://developer.layer.com/docs/android) chat uses a [Atlas-Android](https://github.com/layerhq/Atlas-Android), I am failing to Integrate this. Can any one help me in integrating this in my app?

Thanks

Comment: please add crash log

Comment: hi @USKMobility Here is my log for the crash:
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                          com.layer.sdk.exceptions.LayerException: NOT_AUTHENTICATED (1001) - Cannot create a new conversation when no user is authenticated. at com.layer.sdk.internal.LayerClientImpl.a(LayerClientImpl.java:1620) at com.layer.sdk.internal.LayerClientImpl.newConversation(LayerClientImpl.java:1545) at com.test.wolf.myapp.MessageFragment.fetchLayerConversation(MessageFragment.java:234)

Comment: But when i run the app for atleast 4-5 times the user gets authenticated.

Comment: @SantonuBuragohain post your code where you want to create a new conversation

Comment: @Pooya i have a singleton class where i m creating a layer connection. How can i post the full code here?